# Sonarlint prompting to "Refactor code so that stream pipeline is used"

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, sonarlint, functional-interface

I was using a stream based approach to map-reduce my `List<Map<String,String>>` to a `List<CustomObject>` . The following code was used for the stream

```java
List<Map<String,String>> mailVariable = (List<Map<String, String>>) processVariables.get("MAIL_MAP");

1| List<CustomObject> detList = mailVariable
2|                                      .stream()
3|                                      .flatMap(getEntry)
4|                                      .filter (isEmpty)
5|                                      .reduce(new ArrayList<CustomObject>(),accumulateToCustomObject,combiner);
```

I was analyzing my code using sonarLint and got the following error on line 2 and 3

> Refactor this code so that stream pipeline is used. squid:S3958

I am infact using stream and returing the value from the terminal operation as suggested [here](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/java8/RSPEC-3958). Is there anything I'm doing wrong ?. Could any one suggest the correct way to write this code ?

```java
// following are the functional interface impls used in the process

Function<Map<String,String>, Stream<Entry<String,String>>> getEntry = data -> data.entrySet().stream();

Predicate<Entry<String, String>> isEmpty                            = data -> data.getValue() != null
                                                                                    || !data.getValue().isEmpty() 
                                                                                    || !data.getValue().equals(" ");

BinaryOperator<ArrayList<CustomObject>> combiner                = (a, b) -> {
                                                                                ArrayList<CustomObject> acc = b;
                                                                                acc.addAll(a);
                                                                                return acc;
                                                                            };

BiFunction<ArrayList<CustomObject>,Entry<String,String>,ArrayList<CustomObject>> accumulateToCustomObject = (finalList, eachset) -> {
                /* reduction process happens            
                   building the CustomObject..
                */
                return finalList;
            };
```

Comment: What is the SQID? or the complete message from Sonar?

Comment: Hi Naman, I have added the SQID in the answer now, kindly check :)

Comment: And this happens with which version of Sonar? Did you try **4.15**? Reasons = [this](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2470), [this](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2469) and [that](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/QGfPTRHNG_U)

Comment: Im using the Version 6.7.5 (build 38563) . It does looks like a false positive. I'm an infact returning the terminal value contrary to what the SQID says.

Comment: What if you replace the `reduce` wth `map(...).collect(...)`?

Comment: Coincedence :) . I just did that and it worked . Thanks for your help @Naman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206686/discussion-between-alan-lal-and-naman).

Comment: Cool. Raise it as a bug to Sonar(not sure where do they track) if that's the case. It should not have pointed that the stream is not consumed via `reduce`.

Comment: `fix             y                  our                  inden                  tat   ion`

Answer (score 0):

Update:: I have found a workaround to this problem by splitting my map-reduce operation into a map and collect operation like so. That particular lint error is showing up now

```java
List<AlertEventLogDetTO> detList = mailVariable
                                                    .stream()
                                                    .flatMap(getEntry)
                                                    .filter (isEmpty)
                                                    .map(mapToObj)
                                                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

Function<Entry<String,String>,AlertEventLogDetTO> mapToObj = eachSet -> {
                String tagString = null;
                String tagValue  = eachSet.getValue();

                try{
                    tagString = MapVariables.valueOf(eachSet.getKey()).getTag();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    tagString = eachSet.getKey();
                }

                if(eventTags.contains(tagString)){
                    AlertEventLogDetTO entity = new AlertEventLogDetTO();
                    entity.setAeldAelId(alertEventLog.getAelId());
                    entity.setAelTag(tagString);
                    entity.setAelValue(tagValue);

                    return entity;
                }

                return null;
            };
```